# Problem with laravel/ui in laravel when updating package while upgrading to the latest version of Laravel

Tags: composer-php, laravel-ui

I am currently upgrading from Laravel 5 to 8 although I'm not sure if that is relevant or not. I am running PHP 8 in a docker environment having just upgraded from php 7.3. I have deleted my vendor folder, updated composer.json to run all the latest versions of my packages and run composer install. I am getting the error below:

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/ui ^3.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v3.3.0]
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.3 (conflict analysis result)
```

I am confused by the top line. What exactly is it trying to tell me? I am obviously requesting version ^3.3 of the package. Is it telling me how I need to specifiy this in composer.json ([v3.3.0])? I have tried writing it as v3.3.0, 3.3.0 and ^3.3 and always I get the same 'Problem'. I am also getting the 'conflict analysis result' errors for other packages below this although I'll assume for now that these are separate and unrelated issues which I will address after I have resolved this issue. Can anybody suggest how I can go about resolving this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check for more details? What does `composer why-not laravel/ui 3.3.0` print?